# Delegates and Threading - Which thread manages the invoked method?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I'm relatively new to delegates and still find them somewhat confusing.  The way I want to implement them requires invoking a delegate from one thread to another thread.  Which thread will execute the method?  I'll write some example code here:

```
    public delegate void MyDel();       

    public class main()
    {   

        Object MyLock = new Object();               
        public volatile int NumRegistered = 0;
        public volatile MyDel Invoker = new MyDel;


        public main()

        {
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadA));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadB));

            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();

            while(true)
            {
                if(int == 2)
                {
                    Invoker();
                    int = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        public void ThreadA()
        {
            MyFirstThread tA = new MyFirstThread(this);             
        }

        public void ThreadB()
        {
            MySecondThread tB = new MySecondThread(this);
        }

        public class MyFirstThread
        {           
            public MyFirstThread(main MyParent)
            {
                lock(MyParent.MyLock)
                {
                    MyParent.Invoker += new MyDel(MethodA);
                    MyParent.NumRegistered++;
                }

                while(true)
                {
                    //do something
                }                   
            }

            public void MethodA()
            {
                //This Method A - What thread will run it?  The "Main" thread or "t1"?
            }
        }

        public class MySecondThread
        {

            public MySecondThread(main MyParent)
            {
                lock(MyParent.MyLock)
                {
                    MyParent.Invoker += new MyDel(MethodB);
                    MyParent.NumRegistered++;
                }

                while(true)
                {
                    //do something
                }               
            }

            public void MethodB()
            {
                //This Method B - what thread will run it?  The "Main" thread or "t2"?
            }               
        }
    }
```

Essentially I'm just trying to learn to write a multithreaded callback "registry" without using the backgroundworker class because I can already do it with the backgroundworker and I want to understand it.  How do I get one thread to inform another thread that it needs to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your two new threads will never end up executing `MethodA` or `MethodB` beucase they never invoke the delegate.  They're defining what method will be executed, they're never actually executing that delegate.  The main thread is the only thread that ever actually tries to invoke the delegate, so it's run in the main thread.